Interface UP but no ping
I have a handful of machines connected to a switch. Most of them can ping the server that's connected to the same switch but a couple can not.
The network interface of the machine in question is up/up and seems to be configured correctly (ran ethtool eth0) but when I ping the server, I get destination host unreachable and 100% packet lost.
Everything is configured with static IPs. I verified the obvious - swapped cables and ruled out IP/mac conflicts. The ports on the switch are enabled.
Each machine has a route setup for the subnet to correct adapter ( 192.XXX.XXX.0 -> eth0)
The other 3 interfaces are bridged - I tried shutting off the bridge as a sanity check but that didn't affect anything (as expected).
Traceroute shows only 1 hop : machineName (IP) 3061.260 ms H! 3069.321 ms H! 3071.245 ms H!
I know it's a pretty broad question but how do i diagnose this?

Do you see the host making ARP queries on this interface when you run a packet capture? Does the other host see ARP queries being received over the interface (and if so, does it reply)? Does the switch increment the port's Rx counters? Are both ports in the same VLAN? Are there any port ACLs on the switch?

I do see ARP requests being made but I don't see a corresponding entry on the server side.

I ran wireshark on the server - I see ARP requests from some of the other machines but not the ones that don't ping.

What is "the server"? What OS is installed? How are the firewalls configured? Can the impacted nodes ping their own addresses? Where is the output of the commands you ran to get the information you presented in your question?

Sounds like home networking, off topic here.

@Zac67 It's not home networking. I can't go into a lot of details (reasons) but the server is running Windows. The "machines" are running a custom linux kernel. They can ping themselves and there is no firewall on them.

Does ARP work? If yes, it's a host issue (local firewall, routing). If not, it's a switch issue and you need to add information to the switch model and its configuration (in text format, using the editor's {} preformat option) to your question.

@Zac67 It works on some and not others which makes me think the switch. Sorry I can't go in more details.

I was able to trace it to a hardware problem with the NICs. Swapped 3 NICs and now everything works fine.
